# detection of parent died

Tags: java, android

Ok, it came time to write my first question:

**How can I detect the death of a parent(view)**

Especially when the parent is in the state of termination.

case:

- Activity (A) or generaly View (V) running on UI Thread (UI) got Child (C)
- C is bound with a weak reference (WR) to Thread (T)
- T is not aware of UI (only bound to C)
- T is doing something then passing the result to B
- B is in scope of T
- B is bound by callback to C from UI
- B is notifying C about changes for C to do its job
- T shouldn't do any heavy checks for C
- C shouldn't call T or B

**How can I detect death of C in T and avoid checks if C equals null**

**edit**

I have many idea to resolve this but I wish to have generally approach for this type of actions to serve as a pattern, but in details:

- i got Searching Thread (performing tasks void/searching/finished/pasueed/canceled)
- Thread is started on App creation with task VOID
- some activity gathers data sends it to thread as new search request  and then finish itself
- thread informed starts his search task & fires result intent (activity which displays results)
- this activity makes view for results ands set calltack Thread.setBoundedView(view);
- next thread is passing from its queue a portion of data to its adapter (in its scope )
- adapter notifies view (callback to view is made in Thread.setBoundedView(view) method)
- i wish to know when reference to (view parent) will be orphaned to sttop Thread from job - call wait() for next search) in case :

  - exception
  - onFinish();
  - onPause();

**what i try to achieve:**

- avoid for app to do pointless work
- avoid to overload internet connection
- do not overload the HTTP server

**what solution i excluded:**

- loop for view equality to null checks
- using onAttachedToWindow()/onDetachedFromWindow () as its available from API 12
- hooking to ViewTreeObserver() and registering listener fails 
  is cheeking isAlive and unregistering listener 
  (i wish to avoid cheeks for listener in loop also the same as cheeks for view)

Comment: Could you post an actual example with code? Depending on what your doing, there might be a better way to organize everything

Comment: @Jonathan727 i made an edit